# REFERENCES and VIEW DEFINITION permissions to a user on an alias data type

Tags: sql-server, security

I created a new type and a new user:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MY_TYPE FROM varchar (128) NULL
GO
CREATE USER MyUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO
```

Then if I don't grant any permissions to that user on my type, then I cannot see definition of that type:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'MyUser';
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.types where name = 'MY_TYPE';
--returns nothing
REVERT
GO
```

According to [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175808(v=sql.105).aspx):

> *VIEW DEFINITION granted to individual entities allows the grantee to
>   see metadata for the specified entity.*

So if I grant VIEW DEFINITION permission:

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON TYPE::dbo.MY_TYPE TO MyUser;
```

and repeat the test, I get the information from sys.types. This is OK.

The questions is why I can solve that issue by granting REFERENCES permission?

```
REVOKE VIEW DEFINITION ON TYPE::dbo.MY_TYPE FROM MyUser;
GRANT REFERENCES ON TYPE::dbo.MY_TYPE TO MyUser;
GO

EXECUTE AS USER = 'MyUser';
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.types where name = 'MY_TYPE';
--see the result here!!!
REVERT
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, it looks like *any* permission on the type is sufficient to see the metadata for it. For a more in depth answer, look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx).